# redirect and load data dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have a menu. Each item in the menu is linked to a form. So in my entire application when an enduser clicks the menu item any time the page to be redirected to the particular(xyz)page and the form to be displayed in a div in that xyz page. Can anyone give me idea how to do this one either in jquery or in javascript whatever it is. I google it a lot but i didnt find the correct solution.

Here is my code what i wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.load').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'patient_account.php';
    return false;
    $("a").click(function()
{
$.ajax({
url : $(this).attr("href"),
success : function (data) {
$("#dynamicContent").html(data);
}
});
 return false;
});
```

It is redirecting to next page but it is not loading the form related to menu item in the page where it is required.

Thank you in advance,
Ramsai

Answer (score 0):

Simply use hyperlinks

```
<a href="xyz.htm" >XYZ Form</a>
```

I am sorry but I don't understand what is the problem you are facing. If it is to show different pages on clicking a menu item then simply provide hyperlink.

Comment: if i am  in xyz.php then i click on menu item the page to be redirected to pqr.php and the form linked to that menu item to be displayed in prescribe div.

Comment: You should place the particular form in the prescribed div in pqr.php and link to pqr.php from the menu in xyz.php

Comment: i had around 35 forms based on the link item in the menu and also clinet wants the functionality that when click on menu item it should be redirected to the page and display the concern form in the div in that page Thank you in advance

Comment: Then make 35 pages, each with a form and simply redirect as stated above. I am sorry, but this is very simple. I don't see why you can accomplish this.

Comment: i already did this thing but client is asking dynamically with jquery. So i am google a lot but i didnt fnd it

Comment: If he says Dynamically with jQuery then it means you have to load it in the same page. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/